# biber in WinEdt

Tags: biber, winedt

After setting up WinEdt (10.3 64-bit) to use Biber as described in [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations/154755#154755) I ran into a problem:

Biber looks for log-files `bookXX-blx.blg`, where XX is the chapter number. These are present in `/book/TeXAux`, but Biber apparently tries to find them in `/book`. How do I pass the correct location to Biber?

Comment: I doubt that biber looks for a blg-file, its input are bcf-file. And I never use TeXAux as imho it only makes life more difficult  -- as you just discovered.

Comment: Biber should be looking for one `.bcf` and possibly several `.bib`s, but not for `.blg`s, especially not for `-blx.blg`s (if you use BibTeX there are `-blx.bib`s and possibly `-blx.aux`s for several refsections, but those shouldn't be needed by Biber). I'd love to see an example (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) where Biber has to look for those files. Anyhow, this again shows that "build" subdirectories are the work of the devil and should be avoided at all costs. So the only solution that I can wholeheartedly recommend is to stop using a "build" folder ...

Comment: ... But I doubt that is what you want to hear, so I suggest you have a look at §3.3. *Input/Output File Locations* of the [Biber documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/biber/documentation/biber.pdf). You probably want to try calling something like `biber --input-directory=./TeXAux <basename>` instead of just `biber <basename>`.

Comment: Any news here? Did the suggestions work? Can you share more about your folder and document setup? Does Biber really complain about not finding `-blx.blg` files?

Comment: Adding the --input-directory=./TeXAux to the command line works, but only if the bib-file is moved to `TeXAux` and the `\addbibresource` is changed accordingly. Of course, this puts the idea of separating input and intermediate files _ad absurdum_. MikTeX is set up is standard except for a `localtexmf` in `/MyDocuments`. The book project resides in its own folder under `/MyDocuments`.

Comment: Mhhh, that surprises me even with `--input-directory` Biber should search the current working directory according to the manual. Does `--output-directory` give better results?

Comment: The output already ends up in `TeXAux`, so there seems no point in setting it explicitly.